# How to get number of days without using TRUNC in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to get the number of days between `SYSDATE` and a column in one of my tables without using TRUNC since I need the timestamp to be included within the subtraction.

I am trying to achieve something similar to the code below but without using TRUNC

```
select * from table_name where trunc(sysdate) - trunc(column_name) > 60;
```

Note that `column_name` is a Timestamp not a Date.

Comment: The following error will be generated when not using `trunc()`: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER`

Comment: Yes its a timestamp

Comment: It would be very helpful if you told us the actual business requirement (expressed in plain English, not in code). For example, if there had been no data type conflict, would the condition in the WHERE clause actually be the correct one? Are you looking to compare the truncated (date-only portion) of the column timestamp and current calendar date? Or what else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an INTERVAL datatype to define an interval. `to_dsinterval()` converts a string of the format `DD HH24:MI:SS' to an interval, in this case of exactly sixty days:

```
select * from table_name 
where column_name < sysdate - to_dsinterval('60 0:0:0');
```

Comment: Interesting. Some - if not all - of the other solutions should work as well, so there must be something unusual in your set-up which is not mentioned in your question. But I'm glad you got something which works.

Comment: I verified the other solutions as well. Btw, is it possible to store the number 60 in a variable and use the variable within `to_dsinterval()`?? So that I use the variable instead of the number 60.

Comment: @samg - you could do `sysdate - numtodsinterval(60, 'day')`, or `sysdate - 60 * interval '1' day`, and then the 60 can be replaced with a variable. (Although I might use `systimestamp` rather than `sysdate` just so the data types match - implicit conversion will handle it anyway though.)

Comment: @AlexPoole - I agree about using systimestamp. In fact I used that in my original solution but ended up using sysdate to rule it out as the cause of the ORA-00932.

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
select * from table_name where column_name <= sysdate - 60;
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name < sysdate - interval '60' day;
```

Comment: This does not return correct data. It returns 0 records when it should return 2 records based on my data.

Comment: @samg Please post your data then

Comment: `19-APR-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK`

`19-APR-18 12.00.00.000000000 AM AMERICA/NEW_YORK`

Comment: @samg You could try `<=`

Comment: Or you can do:  `where column_name < sysdate - interval '60' day`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try `select req_columns from MyTable where sysdate - column > 60`.

You can try below query if one of the column is timestamp.

```
select * from Mytable where sysdate - to_date(to_char(colTimeStamp, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI:SS') > 60
```

Comment: The following error will be generated when not using `trunc()`: `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND got NUMBER`

Comment: You can filter the records using where clause

Comment: Updated column, my problem is that the column is of datatype timestamp

Comment: You can use to_char and to_date functions